# How to enable a specific data connection via VBA in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, vba, macros

I'm building a worksheet that will automatically run a web query. Ideally, this will run automatically, without any user intervention. But sometimes the connection is blocked by Excel's security settings and requires the user to authorize access.  Short of enabling all connections globally, what is the best way to deal with this?  Is there way to enable just this one connection via VBA?

Comment: Sometimes using the record macro feature and then viewing the underlying VBA allows you to answer your own question, or at least ask a more specific question.

Comment: This is related to the security settings of each computer. If it is controlled by the administrator, it may not be modified even if the macro is recorded.